# how to change some values in defaultConfig in gradle script?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to build the application for many brands. How to change applicationId in defaultConfig?

```
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled false
        applicationId = ""
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
```

And Gradle script like, but it's not working

```
    task buildForBrand {
       applicationId = "abc.${newBrand}"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Build Variants. Its overwrite your defaultConfig & you can also add more variable like base_url etc. For Ex:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourApp.pkg"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        buildFlavor1 {
            applicationId "com.yourApp.pkg1"
        }
        buildFlavor2 {
            applicationId "com.yourApp.pkg2"
        }
    }
}
```

For more details go this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html).

Comment: can I pass applicationId in gradle script task. So i use command line for buulding.